# Como puedo saber si la tabla existe

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Ell problema es que no se como puedo comprobar ese logeo. actualmente hago directamente una consulta a una tabla, cuando existe perfecto no pasa nada, me muestra la información. cuando no existe me tira el siguiente error:

```
Unexpected '<'
```

mi codigo en php:

```
    <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include('conexion.php');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    $usuario= $_POST['usuario'];

    $result  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from $usuario") or mysqli_error($con);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $arr[] = $row;
        }
        $json = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        echo $json;
}
?>
```

Comment: Unexpected '<' puede ser dentro de tu archivo conexion.php

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el estilo orientado a objeto para saber el numero de registros obtenido;

```
 $mysqli_result->num_rows;
```

Esto arroja un numero entero, 0 en el caso que no exista ningun registro con los criterios que buscas;

un ejemplo:

```
$mysqli_result->num_rows;

if($mysqli_result->num_rows > 0){
    //encontro registros existentes
}else{
    //No encontro ningun registro
}
```

Referencia http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

Puedes determinar primero si existe la tabla con un Query, utilizando `SHOW TABLES LIKE` si el valor es igual a 1, quiere decir que existe la tabla:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include('conexion.php');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    $usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
    if ($result = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$usuario'")) {
        if($result->num_rows == 1) {
            //La tabla existe
            $query  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from $usuario");
            while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                $arr[] = $row;
            }
            $json = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            echo $json;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "La tabla no existe";
    }            
}
?>
```

Comment: me tira el siguiente error _Unexpected '<'_ exista o no exista la tabla.

Comment: busca en la linea donde muestra el error, talvez, escribiste de más un < en el código